# Please explain this file in /sys class thermal

Tags: file-system, files

In /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type, it reads "pa".

There are also other ones in other folders, like "ddr", "cpu-1-0" and "gpuss-0".

What do they mean? Any documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Power Amplifier. DDR RAM. CPU. GPU. They are defined by the OEM in thermal zones' drivers (embedded with Linux kernel).

Comment: Any documentation to check the type (at least for common ones)? I can't find it online.